# CardDav (iCloud) what can be a reason for patches forbidden responses?

Tags: icloud, carddav

Does anyone else also noticed strange forbidden responses for existing vcard files updates?

See my curl example:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://p52-contacts.icloud.com/1........4/carddavhome/card/53cd4fa9-6fb0-40c3-9975-ff41909c7d9c.vcf' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic [secret]' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/vcard; charset=utf-8' \
--data-raw 'BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Last;contact-update_simple;Middle;Prefix;Suffix
FN:Prefix contact-update_simple Last Suffix
UID:53cd4fa9-6fb0-40c3-9975-ff41909c7d9c
END:VCARD'
```

Response most time is "403 Forbidden" - but some calls seems to pass.

Comment: I think the most likely reason is that you are sending invalid vCards. Maybe incorrect quoting, wrong charset encoding, duplicate UIDs, etc. Do you have an example of a rejected vCard?